# Sum of two subharmonic functions is subharmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, semicontinuous-functions

> **Definition** $:$ Let $G \subseteq \mathbb C$ be a domain. A function $s : G \longrightarrow \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}$ is said to be subharmonic if
>
> $(1)$ $s$ is upper semicontinuous.
>
> $(2)$ given $D \subset \subset G$ and a continuous function $h : \overline D \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ with $h \rvert_{D}$ harmonic, if $s \leq h$ on $\partial D,$ then $s \leq h$ in $D.$

> **Problem** $:$ Show that sum of two subharmonic functions is subharmonic.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1380367/512080) I find one approach. But the answerer was himself confused about one of his arguments as to why there exist continuous functions $\alpha, \beta$ with $f \leq \alpha$ and $g \leq \beta$ such that $\alpha + \beta = u + \varepsilon.$ Since $f$ and $g$ are both upper semicontinuous we can get hold of decreasing sequences of continuous functions $\{\alpha_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{\beta_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ such that $\alpha_n \downarrow f$ and $\beta_n \downarrow g$ as $n \to \infty.$ But it is not quite clear to me as to why we can always get hold of a continuous function $\alpha$ such that $f \leq \alpha \leq u - g + \varepsilon$ using compactness of $\partial D.$ Any suggestion in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you use the characterization of subharmonic via the Laplacian? Namely $f$ is subharmonic on $G$ if and only if $\bigtriangleup f \geq 0$ on $G$.

Comment: @Wintermute$:$ Subharmonic functions are not necessarily $C^2.$ The characterization you are referring to is only valid for $C^2$-subharmonic functions. The function $z \mapsto |z|$ is one of the functions.

Comment: Show that subharmonic is equivalent with usc and submean integral inequality and then the result follows immediately

Comment: @Conrad$:$ Could you please give me some hint?

Comment: harmonic functions satisfy the integral mean value property

Comment: @Conrad$:$ I think I got it. Let $a \in G$ and let $r \gt 0$ be such that $B_r (a) \subset \subset G.$ Now let $0 \lt \rho \leq r.$ If $s$ is constant on $B_{\rho} (a)$ then we have nothing to prove. Because given any $z \in \partial B_{\rho} (a)$ there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $B_{\rho} (a)$ such that $z_n \to z$ as $n \to \infty.$ But then by upper semicontinuity of $s$ it follows that $$s(a) = \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} s(z_n) \leq s(z).$$ Hence the submean integral inequality holds automatically. contd...

Comment: @Conrad$:$ ...contd If $s$ is not constant on $B_{\rho}(a)$ then by the maximum principle for subharmonic functions there exists $b \in \partial B_{\rho}(a)$ such that $$s(b)=\max\limits_{z \in \overline{B_{\rho}(a)}}s(z) \gt s(a).$$ Since $s$ is upper semicontinuous and bounded above on $\partial B_{\rho}(a)$ there exists a continuous function $h$ on $\partial B_{\rho} (a)$ such that $s \leq h \leq s(b)$ with $h(b) \lt s(b).$ Then $h$ has a unique harmonic continuation in $B_{\rho}(a).$ Then by the second property of subharmonic functions it follows that $s \leq h$ on $B_{\rho}(a).$ ...contd

Comment: @Conrad$:$ ...contd So we have $$s(a) \leq h(a) = \frac {1} {2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} h (a + \rho e^{it})\ dt.$$ Can we somehow finish it from here?

Comment: @Conrad$:$ I made a mistake in my penultimate comment. We can have a continuous function $h$ on the boundary such that $s \leq h$ and $h$ will have a harmonic extension in the ball and hence $s \leq h$ in the ball as well by the second property of subharmonic functions. Nothing much can be said. All other reasoning seems fine to me. But I got stuck at the fag end. Any help would be warmly appreciated.

Comment: I think I can feel the light now. For $0 \lt \rho \leq r$ and $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$ define $f \left (\lambda e^{it} \right ) = s \left (a + \lambda \rho e^{it} \right ), g \left (\lambda e^{it} \right ) = h \left (a + \lambda \rho e^{it} \right ).$ Let $h \rvert_{\partial B_{\rho} (a)} = u.$ Then we have $$f \left (\lambda e^{it} \right ) \leq g \left (\lambda e^{it} \right ) = \frac {1} {2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} P_{\lambda} (\theta - t)\ g \left (e^{it} \right )\ dt.$$ Putting $\lambda = 0$ we have $$s(a) \leq \frac {1} {2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} u \left (a + \rho e^{it} \right )\ dt.$$

Comment: Now by changing $u$ by $u_n$ with $u_n \downarrow s$ on $\partial B_{\rho} (a)$ and using dominated convergence theorem (by letting $n \to \infty$) it follows that $$s(a) \leq \frac {1} {2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} s \left (a + \rho e^{it} \right )\ dt,$$ as required.

Comment: The converse is easy as maximum principle holds for any upper semicontinuous function satisfying submean integral inequality.